# wrong indentation of multi-line python statement in emacs

Tags: python, emacs, tabs, indentation, multiline

Using Tab, I can only indent the code in the style like this:

```
for ave, sd, dG, seq_pair in zip(open(predictedAve), open(predictedSD),
open(dG), open(dynLis)):
```

instead of this:

```
for ave, sd, dG, seq_pair in zip(open(predictedAve), open(predictedSD),
                                 open(dG), open(dynLis)):
```

The former style is ugly. And what's worse, it will make the indentation of statements inside the `for` loop impossible. How can I achieve the latter indentation by Tabs in emacs?

Comment: http://www.pement.org/emacs_tabs.htm ?

Comment: What version of Emacs and what python mode are you using? I tried running Emacs 24.1 with `emacs -Q`, pasting in your first code block, moving to the second line and pressing tab. The code as indented in the second block is the result. What do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if you have `python-mode` enabled?

Comment: Or perhaps there is some syntax error, like it thinks you are in a string.

Comment: It is enabled. I found later that the problem is caused by another incomplete statement in the buffer. Thanks anyway.